# Restlet path param does not work

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, restlet

Below is my routing

```
public Restlet createInboundRoot(){
 Router router = new Router(getContext());
router.attach("account/profile",UserProfile.class);
```

Following is the Resource class UserProfile.java

```
@post
@path("add")
public void addUser(User user){

@post
@path("modify")
public void modifyUser(User user){

@post
public void test(){//only this is called
```

I want to invoke one resource class and do couple of identical functions for a resource class. That means, my above resource class handles functions related to the UserProfiles such as add, modify.
URL are:
account/profile/add => to add a user
account/profile/modify => to modify a user

anyway, above my implementation doesn't work as only the test() method can be invoked through account/profile/

I tried with Pathparams as well.But it also didnot work. 
For path params:

```
router.attach("account/profile/{action}",UserProfile.class);
```

was added and in the resource class,

```
@post
@path("{action}")
public void addUser(@pathparam("action") String action, User user){
```

Anyone tell me where is my problem.

Comment: Can you post your err log here?

Comment: Thanks karthi for attention. There is no errors thrown.. Server just returns 403 as response

Comment: Well! It means the resource you are trying to access is exist but the server unable to give a proper response. You can try these things, make sure you directory has all permissions and specify a produce type either json or XML by using @ Produces annotation and give a try with @put or @ get methods. Sometimes post is culprit.

Comment: Thanks Karthi..  I tried with single method annotated @POST with single ULR to the source and then it worked. I don't see any permission issue. This problem rises when 2 URLs calls this resource.

Comment: Any has any thought please ?

Comment: as a side note, don't use action names in the path of your resources. a resource is more about state, note action. If you want action, use the HTTP verbs.

Answer (score 0):

The way you attach your `UserProfile` server resource is a bit strange. I think that you mixed the native routing of Restlet and the one from the JAXRS extension.

I made some tests regarding your use case and I was able to have the behavior you expect. I used the version 2.3.5 of Restlet.

Here is what I did:

- Since you want to use JAXRS, you need to create a `JaxRsApplication` and attach it on the component:

  ```
  Component component = new Component();
  component.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, 8182);

      // JAXRS application
      JaxRsApplication application
         = new JaxRsApplication(component.getContext());
      application.add(new MyApplication());

      // Attachment
      component.getDefaultHost().attachDefault(application);

      // Start
      component.start();
  ```
- The application simply list the server resources you want to use but doesn't define routing and paths:

  ```
  import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

  public class MyApplication extends Application {
      public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
          Set<Class<?>> rrcs = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
          rrcs.add(AccountProfileServerResource.class);
          return rrcs;
      }
  }
  ```
- The server resource defines handling methods and associated routes:

  ```
  import javax.ws.rs.POST;
  import javax.ws.rs.Path;

  @Path("account/profile/")
  public class AccountProfileServerResource {
      @POST
      @Path("add")
      public User addUser(User user) {
          System.out.println(">> addUser");
          return user;
      }

      @POST
      @Path("modify")
      public User modifyUser(User user) {
          System.out.println(">> modifyUser");
          return user;
      }

      @POST
      public void test() {
          System.out.println(">> test");
      }
  }
  ```
- When I call the different paths, right methods are called:

  - `http://localhost:8182/account/profile/modify`: the `modifyUser` method is called
  - `http://localhost:8182/account/profile/add`: the `addUser` method is called
  - `http://localhost:8182/account/profile/`: the `test` method is called

Hope it helps you,
Thierry